# I'm making a 2D game engine with JAVA Eclipse 2021-06 but it is underperforming in FPS for my NVidia RTX 3070

Tags: java, performance, game, eclipse

This is my first Stack Exchange question, so please bare with me. I'm following this tutorial on youtube by [The Cherno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFYT7Lqt1h8&list=PLlrATfBNZ98eOOCk2fOFg7Qg5yoQfFAdf&index=2), Im only up to episode 16 and I have done this on another laptop before and had 3000 FPS. On my new [laptop](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-rog-zephyrus-15-6-qhd-gaming-laptop-amd-ryzen-9-16gb-memory-nvidia-geforce-rtx-3070-1tb-ssd-eclipse-grey-eclipse-grey/6448848.p?skuId=6448848), im only getting 600 FPS. I dont think it is the code but everything I have looked up has just led me to minecraft issuse with FPS. A lot of things I have read said I should make sure its using the correct GPU and change my setting in the NVidia Control panel. Everything I have tried hasnt helped sadly. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Please let me know if any more information is needed

---

**Below is my main class which holds the game loop, widow initialization, and rendering methods**

---

```
package com.SaltineCracker.rain;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.SaltineCracker.rain.graphics.Screen;


/*
 Holds the game loop
 Initializes the Threads
 Has the start and stop functions
 Creates the screen ad has the Render and Update Methods
*/
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Sets the screen width and height
    public static int width = 300;
    // Creates the height with a 16/9 aspect ratio based off width
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    public static String title = "Rain";

    // Creates a new thread
    private Thread thread;
    // Uses JFrame to create the window
    private JFrame frame;
    // Game loop variable
    private boolean running = false;
    
    // Gets the screen class from the graphics folder and makes it available for use
    private Screen screen;
    
    // Creates the image
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // Allows the game to have access to each pixel and the ability to change them
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    
    
    
    public Game()
    {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        // Sets the window size using a method in canvas because the game is extending it
        setPreferredSize(size);
        
        // Creates a new instance of the screen class
        screen = new Screen(width, height);
        
        // Creates new instance of JFrame
        frame = new JFrame();
    }
    
    
    
    // synchronized allows the threads to run together
    public synchronized void start()
    {
        // Starts game loop
        running = true;
        
        // Creates a new thread object and then starts it
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        // Once run, it initializes and starts the run function
        thread.start();
    }



    // Try's to properly join the threads and then force closes them
    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        // Stops game loop
        running = false;
    
        try 
        {
            thread.join();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // Game loop gets called automatically because the game implements Runnable
    public void run()
    {
        // Gets the time right when the program is started
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
        double delta = 0;   
        
        int frames = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        
        while (running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            
            
            // Makse's sure that the program runs only 60 times a second
            while (delta >= 1)
            {
                update();
                
                // Counting all the amount of times it updates
                updates++;
                // Resets the delta variable back to 0
                delta--;
            }
        
            render();
            
            // COunts the amount of frames run a second
            frames++;
            
            // Happens once per second
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
            {
                timer += 1000;
                
                // Displays the FPS and UPDATES in the tile bar
                frame.setTitle(title + " | " + updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
                
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
    
        stop();
    }
    
    
    
    public void update()
    {
        
    }
    
    
    
    public void render()
    {
        // <pre>-loading data to be rendered, usually pixel information
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        
        if (bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        
        // Clears the screen
        screen.clear();
        // Calls the screen rending method
        screen.render();
    
        // Sets the new buffered image to what ever the Screen class is rendering
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }
        
        // Links the graphics element with the buffer strategy
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        
        // Draws the buffered image at 0, 0 with the height and width
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        
        
        // Removes old graphics
        g.dispose();
        
        // Shows the next buffer strategy
        bs.show();
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creates a new instance of the game
        Game game = new Game();
        
        
        
//      --- Canvas Frame Customization ---
    
    
        // Removes the ability to resize
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle(Game.title);
        // Adds the game object as a component
        game.frame.add(game);
        // Sizes the game
        game.frame.pack();
        // Closes the program and not just the window
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // Shows the window
        game.frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
        
        // Uses the start method and starts the game
        game.start();
    }
    
}
```

---

**This is my second class called Screen**

---

```
package com.SaltineCracker.rain.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

/*
 
 Gets initialized in the Game class, Game Function
 This Class handles rendering the screen data
 
 */
public class Screen {
    
    private int width, height;
    public int[] pixels;
    
    public int[] tiles = new int[64 * 64];
    
    private Random random = new Random();
    
    public Screen(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        
        // Creates an integer for each pixel on the screen
        pixels = new int[width * height];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 64 * 64; i++)
        {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // Sets all pixels in pixels array to black to clear the screen
    public void clear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // Runs through every pixel 
    public void render()
    {
        // Loops through Y pixels
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Temporary variable to not mess with Y
            int yy = y;
            
            // If the object is out of bounds of array, it wont crash
            if (yy < 0 || yy >= height ) break;
            
            
            // Loops through X pixels
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // Temporary variable to not mess with X
                int xx = x;
                
                // If the object is out of bounds of array, it wont crash
                if (xx < 0 || xx >= width ) break;
                
                // Gets the tile by the pixel amount, 4 is the square root of the pixel length
                int tileIndex = ((x >> 4) & 63) + ((y >> 4) & 63) * 64;
                
                // Gets the pixel index and sets it to a color
                pixels[x + y * width] = tiles[tileIndex];
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

**This image shows what GPU it is using**

---

[image]

---

**This image shows what GPU 0 is listed as**

---

[image]

---

**This image shows what my NVidia Control Global settings are**

---

[image]

---

**This image shows what my NVidia Control settings are for Javaw.exe**

---

[image]

Comment: There's not much to review here as you are under the wrong assumption, that you can make a game engine using normal user interface code like swing/awt. To achive performance, you'll have to program your graphics hardware more or less directly, e.g. using OpenGL (for java see https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) which will be a long journey in itself. Frankly, my advice for the beginning programmer is finding a different project first. 3d engines are probably the most complicated thing you can aim for using the most convoluted programming interface imaginable.

Comment: I do agree with the fact that making a 3D game engine is a very hard task, that's why I'm purely doing a 2D game engine. I do plan on learning OpenGL for which the Cherno also has a series to explain it and how to implement it. I've also have done a decent amount of messing with Unity, same with just programing different projects. I purely just wanted to go for what seems to be a decently long and difficult project to occupy any downtime and to learn a decent amount from it. The main question I guess for this was any suggestions for my computer settings on how to fix an underperforming GPU.

Comment: Could you share what CPUs you have in both of your laptops? I'm starting to think that `Screen.render()` might be the problem here.

Comment: @mindoverflow My old computer had an Intel 5 Core i5 9th gen and my new one has an AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS

Comment: They seem rather similar. Do you have access to both computers? Might be worth a try to benchmark the parts I suspect.

Comment: I looked again, you'd need to benchmark the `screen.clear()`, `screen.render()` and the `for` loop after these two inside of `Game.render()`. Some simple timing using `System.nanoTime()` should suffice. Don't print the time take on every frame (slow, instead sum the times ad divide through the frames rendered) and run the game for at least 30s (JVM is slow on startup).

Comment: @mindoverflow, So I did the timings benchmark and this is what I got. This is in nanoseconds, 4_500 for screen.clear(), 42_000 for system.render(), 5_000 for the for loop. I then checked g.drawimage and it's getting about 100_000, and bs.show is getting about 1_500_000. As a whole, it's about 2_000_000, sadly I'm new at using Buffered Strategy so I don't fully understand how to optimize this process.

Comment: Well, I'm at my wit's end here ^^;. Perhaps it's just Java not playing nice with your hardware for some reason, you could try asking about this on stackoverflow. Lastly, while I don't recommend learning a library AND Java at the same time, you could check out LibGDX. There are some good tutorials, I can recommend Brent Aureli's videos.

Comment: @mindoverflow definitely thank you for the help and I will definitely be looking up LibGDX for help and try to post this on Stackoverflow

Comment: `please bare with me` I might come back to that later.